# Play framework Scala Deployment - using the dist task

Tags: scala, playframework

For a few days, I'm trying to deploy my web application on my server.
I followed the procedure, everything goes well, except that once started, when I type the address of my site, nothing appears.

My procedure :

1. I created a zip with "dist"
2. I unzipped it in the "public_html" file of my server
3. I launched the application from "bin" as follows :

   myapp/bin/myapp -Dplay.http.secret.key='the key
4. I get the following response:

   [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod) (no global state)

   [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

This is the first time I have my own server.  Where is my error?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: What do you do to "go to your website"? Go to `http://your server:9000`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I also tried to start with other ports, for example 8080.

Comment: And does your application have a route on `/`?

Comment: Yes, I just took the tuto template from play. I compile with java 8 and on the server there is openjdk 8, is there any compatibility problem ?

Comment: What is the output of running `curl -v localhost:9000` from your server?

When you say "nothing appears" can you be more specific about whether there is an http response (with what code), a timeout, or something else?

Comment: I understood the problem, the server I am using is based on apache and has a proxy which is disturbing. I have to use a returned proxy.

To answer your question, I see my application as a folder and no activity from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the part that stands out to me:

> Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

That's an IPv6 address. Is it possible that you don't have IPv6 routing set up from wherever you're "going to your website" to the server? If that's the case, you could have everything on the play/scala side set up correctly, but still not get the result you want.